# MYSQL multiple trigger for different tables?

Tags: mysql, triggers

is there a possibility to add more as one trigger before insert event in mysql?

at the moment i have:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_identityuser
  BEFORE INSERT ON identityuser
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF new.Id IS NULL THEN
      SET new.Id = uuid();
    END IF;
  END
;;
```

this generate a uuid for the table identityuser. now i want to generate a second uuid for the table claims.

maybe something like that:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_identityuser
  BEFORE INSERT ON identityuser
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF new.Id IS NULL THEN
      SET new.Id = uuid();
    END IF;
  END;
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_claims
 BEFORE INSERT ON claims
 FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF new.Id IS NULL THEN
      SET new.Id = uuid();
    END IF;
  END;
;;
```

is it possible or have i to solve it otherwise?

Comment: I believe from 5.6 or 5.7 it’s possible to do the same event triggers and timing could not find a source to confirm it

Comment: Found it “As of MySQL 5.7.2, it is possible to define multiple triggers for a given table that have the same trigger event and action time.” source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html